# how to link an app to a web database?

Tags: html, mobile

I am trying to make a mobile app that could show the menu of the day, which is previously only available on the website. I'm wondering how can I connect my mobile app to the website database? I know it might be dumb to you guys but I'm a novice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build an API for your app to consume. I recently wrote a blog post about doing this through [JSON with ExpressionEngine](http://paramore.is/think/entry/a-simple-rest-server-with-expressionengine/)